# Python com problemas com variável tipo float

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, float, pycharm

Galera escrevi um programa onde eu decremento uma variável em 0.01 e a partir do terceiro decremento, o python simplesmente passa a reconhecer o valor 0.01 como 0.009999999999988617 e acaba dando problemas no meu código. No código de exemplo abaixo, executem do jeito que está e depois alterem o valor de a para 0.03 ou mais, e vejam o que eu digo. Porque isso ocorre?
a = 0.02
while a != 0.00:
    a -=0.01
    print(a)

Comment: O tipo de dados float é inerentemente impreciso. Se você necessita precisão use outro tipo de dado. Pesquise pela classe Decimal.

Comment: @anonimo Existe em Python o Decimal ?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 [decimal — Aritmética de ponto fixo decimal e ponto flutuante](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/decimal.html)

Answer (score 2):

Isso ocorre naturalmente com números decimais por serem representados um "ponto flutuante" na memória do computador, o que gera certa imprecisão nesse tipo de variável.